# DocumentRoot in Apache on Centos

Tags: apache, php, centos

Есть Centos с Apache и PHP. Как мне закинуть на него страницу PHP? В какую папку и как обращаться? Файл, предположим example.php, ну еще папка со скриптами там есть.

Comment: @anunak, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
grep -i DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Вывод в консоли будет содержать примерно следующее:

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

В нашем случае `/var/www/html` - нужная директория.

Comment: честно не особо понял что за консольная команда. я не админ, а кодер, у меня есть доступ по WinSCP чтобы файлы закидывать

Comment: Как ответ на комментарий: если есть доступ "через WinSCP", то это значит что есть доступ по SSH. Берем клиента типа PuTTY и соединяемся с хостом - там указывается все то же самое, что и в настройках WinSCP. После того как соединение будет установлено, то можно ввести ту самую команду.
Но раз уже есть доступ "через WinSCP", то просто "идем" в директорию `/etc/httpd/conf/`, открываем файл `httpd.conf`, находим строчку, содержащую `DocumentRoot` и смотрим, какая папка указана как `DocumentRoot` для сервера.